# Android, LocationListener.onStatusChanged deprecated,What can replace it

Tags: android, locationlistener

```
onStatusChanged
Added in API level 1
Deprecated in API level 29

public void onStatusChanged (String provider, 
                int status, 
                Bundle extras)
This method was deprecated in API level 29.

This callback will never be invoked on Android Q and above.
This callback will never be invoked on Android Q and above, and providers can be considered as always in the LocationProvider#AVAILABLE state.

Note that this method only has a default implementation on Android R and above, and this method must still be overridden in order to run successfully on Android versions below R. LocationListenerCompat from the compat libraries may be used to avoid the need to override for older platforms.
```

onStatusChanged deprecated
The **Google Location Services API** is officially recommended, but this can only be used if the device has **Google Services**. Unfortunately, my device **does not have Google Services**, so is there any other alternative?

Comment: Nothing needs to.  They deprecated the OUT_OF_SERVICE and TEMPORARILY_OUT_OF_SERVICE states.  They'll just never occur.  This function was deprecated because due to that change, it would never be called.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue on devices below Android 10.

Here is the stack trace;

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void android.location.LocationListener.onStatusChanged(java.lang.String, int, android.os.Bundle)"
       at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:299)
       at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.-wrap0()
       at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:237)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6548)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
```

The unfortunate thing is, it didn't have a reference to any of my source, but it is evident it stems from location listener.

Looking through the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener#onStatusChanged(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)) ,  it says:

> `onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)`

> This method was deprecated in API level 29. This callback will never be invoked on Android Q and above.

The initial implementation was this way:

```kotlin
     val listener = LocationListener {
                         trySendBlocking(it)
                    }
```

Changing it to the snippet below adds a strikethrough to the `super.onStatusChanged` and still crashes because the docs says it was deprecated in API 29

```kotlin
         val listener = object : LocationListener {
                    override fun onLocationChanged(p0: Location) {
                       // handle location here
                    }
        
                    override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String?, status: Int, extras: Bundle?) {
                       // Remove this line
                        super.onStatusChanged(provider, status, extras)
                    }
        
                }
```

Removing `super.onStatusChanged(provider, status, extras)` but leaving the overide ensures that the call is not propagated into the parent abstract class.